# pow for LargeInteger

Tags: java, pow, largenumber, jscience

[`LargeInteger`](http://jscience.org/api/org/jscience/mathematics/number/LargeInteger.html) doesn't seem to have a `pow` function, or if it does, it cannot process `pow(0)` though [`BigInteger` can](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#pow%28int%29).

I have tried to construct my own, but memory seems to spike badly, and there may be an infinite loop as it runs endlessly:

```
public static LargeInteger liPow(LargeInteger base, int exponent){
    if(exponent == 0){
        return LargeInteger.valueOf(1);
    }
    else if(exponent == 1){
        return base;
    }
    else{
        for(int i=1; i<exponent; i++){
            base = base.times(base);
        }
        return base;
    }
}
```

How can a `pow` method be developed for `LargeInteger`?

Comment: Your not actually computing `pow()`, but some larger function `base^(2^exp)`.

Comment: @Mysticial Thank you Mystiicial!  I will definitely look into that!

Comment: Dammit. I deleted my comment just as you responded. Here it is again: use this algorithm: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring

Comment: @Mysticial - I think he/she is trying to.

Comment: @DavidWallace This is pscience's library.  If it's as good as advertised, maybe it won't take a full second to sign ed25519 with java!  ;))

Comment: @DavidWallace Which is why I deleted it in the first place. I thought the OP was trying to sequentially multiply up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LargeInteger, being descended from [Number](http://jscience.org/api/org/jscience/mathematics/number/Number.html#pow%28int%29) does actually have a pow function.

Comment: Thank you Quirlom!  I've noticed that it doesn't complain when the argument isn't `0`.  So I should just check for that instead?  Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: From the [source](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.jscience/jscience/4.3.1/org/jscience/mathematics/number/Number.java#Number.pow%28int%29) it seems like they throw an exception if the exponent is <= 0 thus I would check if the exponent is 0 and return 1.

Comment: Thank you again Quirlon!  I will look further back in the class "chain" for answers next time now that I know what that is if I at least don't know what it's called.  ;))

Answer (score 4):

Each time through your `for` loop, you are effectively squaring the result with this line:

```
base = base.times(base);
```

You would wind up with `base` to the power of (2 to the `exponent` power), not `base` to the power of `exponent`.

Start with `1` and multiply in the `base` each loop.

```
LargeInteger result = LargeInteger.valueOf(1);
for(int i = 0; i < exponent; i++){
    result = result.times(base);
}
return result;
```

For optimization, you can try modifying the algorithm to use [exponentiation-by-squaring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring).

Comment: Thank you rgettman!  I will try to use this after I'm sure `pow` only complains for <= 0.